# M2 | Self Collection | I will pick it up myself option in checkout page

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, shipping-methods, shipping-address

I want to show pickup from shop option in shipping method. The customer can choose either delivery to my address or ill pick up from the shop.
any idea anyone about this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple store pick up modules available for this functionality, you can check them in Magento Marketplace [here](https://marketplace.magento.com/magedelight-storepickup.html).

You can check this one as well, paid but good one:
https://www.magestore.com/store-locator-pickup

Comment: Thanks for replay! Yes, I check these M2 extensions but how could do that? I mean same as in reference image and I want to just store address no need map etc...

Comment: once integrated with that extension, you can enter your store addresses and customize front-end to display the way you want.

Comment: but still, I didn't how can I do that with tabbed or button to change shipping method.